# Internet Explorer 7 is only browser that connects to the Internet

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-connection

Alright, I'm not quite sure what is going on. I recently uninstalled Norton Antivirus, and once I rebooted the computer the only browser that works is Internet Explorer 7. I've turned off the Windows Firewall.

I uninstalled/reinstalled Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. Other programs (such as BitTorrent) still work, though. I upgraded Internet Explorer, and it didn't work untill I restored the computer and was using version 7 again.

I have no idea what is going on. Can anyone help? I tried restoring my computer to before I uninstalled Norton Antivirus, and it didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version/edition of Norton is it?

Comment: Not exactly sure. Was on the laptop when I got it. In the program list it just says "Norton Internet Security (Symantec Corporation)"

Comment: Norton can be set to 'temporarily' block Internet browsing, are you sure it's not set to locked or alike in Norton?  What do the proxy settings look like?  Which version of Windows?

Comment: I can't even open Norton now. When I try to uninstall it, it says files cannot be found. No proxy (I think), Windows Vista.

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall Norton if Windows Restore re-installed it, then Download and run the [Norton Removal tool](https://www-secure.symantec.com/norton-support/jsp/help-solutions.jsp?lg=english&ct=united%20states&docid=20080710133834EN&product=home&version=1&pvid=f-home) and reboot.

Comment: None of the links to download that Removal tool work. :/ I'll keep trying every so often, though.

Comment: They work for me, you may have malware on your PC, see my post here to clean the system, be sure to follow the order given...http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware/157533#157533

Comment: @Moab i consider Norton to be a form of malware :)

Comment: I stopped using Norton back in 2003.