# Internet Explorer connects to the Internet but Chrome does not

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet-explorer, internet-connection

I am having trouble connecting to the Internet with Google Chrome, even though IE works just fine and so does a bunch of other software. Chrome seems to work well on other accounts on the same computer (although I am not sure it is the same executable). On my account, trying to access `google.com` I get the error message `Unable to connect to the Internet`.

I am running Windows 7, and just upgraded to Chrome ver. `37.0.2062.103 m`.

I saw the answers on the web asking to clear `Automatically detect settings` option in the LAN settings, tried it and it does not work with it checked or unchecked (I don't have a proxy server or a configuration script, and IE seems to be running from exactly the same LAN Settings).

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/338453/internet-explorer-7-is-only-browser-that-connects-to-the-internet) may be related, but does not seem to help much.

Thank you very much for your help.

**UPDATE**

- tried uninstalling, restarting  and installing the admin version for all accounts; now the new version cannot connect to the Internet for all users.
- tried the first suggestion in the comments below - removed user profile, disabled extensions, started in incognito mode - all to no avail.

**UPDATE 2** [Oct.3,2014]
  - uninstalled, removed the `%APPDATA%` subdir, installed back, rebooted, still does not work. Remote one still works ok.

Comment: Start Chrome [with extensions disabled](https://superuser.com/questions/254579/how-to-open-google-chrome-with-extensions-disabled-turned-off) and see if that works? Alternatively, install [New Chrome Session](https://bitbucket.org/bradisbell/new-chrome-session/downloads) and  use the script to start a brand new session of Google Chrome with no customization and see if that works (the loss of customization is not permanent)

Comment: @Vinayak first one didn't work. should I try second one or other suggestions? please see the posted update... thanks

Comment: When you say you removed user profile, do you mean you deleted the %appdata%\..\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\ folder? If not, you might want to try the second option too.

Comment: @Vinayak tried second option, does not work either - starts Chrome with 2 tabs, both show "cannot connect to the Internet"

Comment: This is probably not the solution you're looking for, but you might want to try the [portable version of Google Chrome](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) until someone figures this out.

Comment: @Vinayak portable version is a work-around, please feel free to post as an answer, I will gladly upvote it and perhaps accept if nothing else shows up

Comment: If the portable version worked for you, then I guess you should try deleting this folder: ***%appdata%\..\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\*** (make a backup copy, just in case) and start Google Chrome. You'll lose all your customization, history, bookmarks, etc. unless they were synced with Google's servers.

Comment: @Vinayak see latest update, tried could not make it work either

Comment: Any chance you have antivirus or a firewall on the account? You could try disabling it temporarily and see if Chrome works then. My thinking is that you clicked a popup at one point which blocked chrome and not other browsers from accessing the web.
Although I would expect it would have affected the others users on your machine.

Comment: what did you mean by "Remote one still works ok?"

Comment: @Vinayak The Remote version of the Google Chrome works ok (the one that apparently does not use %APPDATA% and perhaps a bunch of other things).

Comment: That's the portable version of Google Chrome, actually. Could you open this page: `chrome://conflicts` and see if Chrome detects any conflicts there? Also visit `chrome://policy` and let me know what you see there.